# Need help in using namespaces with composer autoload

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php

My simple class looks like this:

```
<?php
require_once '../../vendor/autoload.php';
use App\Libraries\user;


class chat{

    private $user;

    public function __constuct(){
        $this->user = new user();       
    }
    public function adduser(){
        //userdata is available
        $userobj = $this->user->adduser($userdata);
    }
}
```

I am trying to create instance of user class but somehow it's giving me error.Fatal error: Call to a member function adduser() on a non-object in /var/www/app/controller/chat.php on line 14. I have checked in composer's autoload_classmap file and I can see the mapping for user class like:

```
'App\\Libraries\\user' => $baseDir . '/app/libraries/User.php',
'App\\Libraries\\DBConnection' => $baseDir . '/app/libraries/Database.php',
```

I am not sure what is missing here to get an instance of user object in 'chat' class using namespace.

user class:

```
<?php
use App\Libraries\DBConnection;
class user{
    public function __construct(){
        $this->db = new DBConnection();
    }

    public function adduser($user){
    //insert operation
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is odd. I've had a similar issue in the past, unfortunately I don't remember the exact fix...

I would check file permissions.

Try adding an entry in the psr-0 section of composer.json to try a different namespace.

If using symfony, check the app-cache.

I'll post more if the solution comes back to me. Sorry that I can't be more helpful at this stage.